# Import css file from node_modules using @wordpress/scripts

Tags: css

I set up a WordPress site locally using a cdn to import [Iconoir](https://iconoir.com/) icons. However, I'd like to host everything locally and installed Iconoir as well as [@wordpress/scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-scripts/) via npm.

I started out with only a single line `src/index.js` to import my custom css code:

```
import '../assets/css/style.scss'
```

My custom css is split up to separate modules, and all of them are imported using `@import url('modules/foo.scss')` syntax in `style.scss`. This is working as expected.

I also tried to import `iconoir.css` from the `node_modules` folder:

1st approach: index.js

```
import '../node_modules/iconoir/css/iconoir.css'
```

2nd approach: style.scss

```
@import url('~iconoir/css/iconoir.css');
```

None of these approaches work. Instead, I get a *Maximum call stack size exceeded* error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/iconoir/css/iconoir.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[4].use[1]!./node_modules/iconoir/css/iconoir.css)
Module parse failed: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

How can I use the local css file in my project?

Comment: The problem vanishes when I remove most of the css from *iconoir.css*, which is a very large file.